# pandas - consolidate first column containing duplicate texts then pivot key and value columns associated to each text

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this (a text element which has multiple computed css keys and values):

```
       text                                               key                       val
0      ["Coronavirus", "Read the latest", "updates fr...                block-size                20px
1      ["Coronavirus", "Read the latest", "updates fr...    border-block-end-color  rgb(255, 255, 255)
2      ["Coronavirus", "Read the latest", "updates fr...  border-block-start-color  rgb(255, 255, 255)
3      ["Coronavirus", "Read the latest", "updates fr...       border-bottom-color  rgb(255, 255, 255)
4      ["Coronavirus", "Read the latest", "updates fr...   border-inline-end-color  rgb(255, 255, 255)
...                                                  ...                       ...                 ...
80948  ["With a mousse-like formula, Sugarpill's Liqu...             margin-bottom                16px
80949  ["With a mousse-like formula, Sugarpill's Liqu...                margin-top                16px
80950  ["With a mousse-like formula, Sugarpill's Liqu...        perspective-origin      243.203px 60px
80951  ["With a mousse-like formula, Sugarpill's Liqu...                text-align                left
80952  ["With a mousse-like formula, Sugarpill's Liqu...          transform-origin      243.211px 60px
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
       text                                                block-size      border-block-end-color    border-block-start-color
0      ["Coronavirus", "Read the latest", "updates fr...   20px            rgb(255, 255, 255)                rgb(255, 255, 255)
...                                                  ...                ...                 ...
n      ["With a mousse-like formula, Sugarpill's Liqu...   20px            rgb(255, 255, 255)                rgb(255, 255, 255)
```

I want to consolidate the text columns so that there is only one instance of it/no duplicates, and pivot `key` and `val` columns that are associated with each unique text instance.

I have tried

`df = df.pivot(index='text', columns='key', values='val')`

but get `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

I tried `pivot_table` instead as suggested in the docs and get `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`.

*I'm new to pandas so maybe there's something I'm missing - this seems like it should be fairly common problem with easy solution, and `pivot` sounds like the tool for the job, but I could have it all wrong. I've tried groupby, stacking/unstacking and resetting index but probably not enough*

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it, but maybe you can use something like:

```
df.set_index(['text', 'ley'])['val'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Followed by some `.ffill()` and then filter for selecting unique cases.

If you provide an example ready-to-use dataset I can give it a try.